# How to open an After Effects cc project in AE cs6?

Tags: cs6, cc-2014, adobe-after-effects

I'm using after effect cc and I want to open the project on another computer using cs6. I collected the files (`file> dependencies > collect file` )
but the project didn't work on cs6

How to open the project on another computer running cs6 or earlier versions like cs5 or cs4?

Comment: Maybe when you save in CC you should choose a downward version.

Comment: there is no options like this

Comment: I have the same issue, but I don't have the "Save a Copy As CS6" option, I only have this options
[![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5gdfU.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5gdfU.png)

Answer (score 5):

The following screenshot says it all.

[image]

Comment: yes you can do this 
but the file will not work on another computer 
because the files isnt collected

Comment: @HassanAlkhateeb In that case, you will need to install a CS6 on your own computer, open the project you saved as a copy for CS6, and collect there...